# access ng-model select control inside ng-include

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, binding, model-binding, angular-ngmodel

I have a created a angularjs application. In the Thread.html page, I am having the combobox to load the strategy list.

```
<select class="txtBox" data-ng-model="editor.strategy">
            <option value="">--Selected Strategy--</option>
            <option data-ng-repeat="s in strategyList" value="{{ s.Name }}">{{ s.Name }}</option>
        </select>
```

I am include the template using ng-include in the same page.

```
<div data-ng-include="'/views/Editor.html'"></div>
```

Inside the editor.js controller, I am able to access the $scope.editor.strategy for the first time. After post the data, I am trying to clear the combobox by seeting $scope.editor = {"strategy":''}. How to reset the combobox from the editor.js controller. I am not sure where I am doing mistake. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to post more of your editor.js code, so we can see how you are populating strategyList.  Since you are using ng-repeat (why not use ng-options?), you'll have to reset strategyList, not editor.strategy.

Comment: It is a json data using ajax call. I just want to reset the combobox to keep the "select strategy" to be selected i.e. that top item in the combobox.

Comment: Can you try setting $scope.editor.strategy = '' instead of $scope.editor = {strategy: ''}?  If you post more of the editor.js code, we can help you quicker.  Are you using simple ajax call or $http and using promises?